# Rshiny output function breaks when using $ operator and filter

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to build a shiny app very closely based on a previous one I have (which works), albeit with a different (though similarly structured) data object underneath.  After changing all the variable and object names, I got the following error:

> Warning: Error in filter_impl: Evaluation error: $ operator is invalid
>   for atomic vectors.

I found a couple of seemingly relevant pages in my searches online:

[$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors :: R shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837964/operator-is-invalid-for-atomic-vectors-r-shiny)

https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1823

Unfortunately the $ operator error seems to be quite a general error message, and neither of these seemed to specifically address my problem.  After some tinkering paring back various elements, I found I could render the plots and tables in the app, provided I didn't use attempt to filter on any of the input fields.

For instance, the following ouptut worked, fine, including the switch that allowed me to turn the whole plot on and off, and alter the heading of the graph with a text input called `filter1`.

```
output$emoPlot <- renderPlotly({

if(input$prefilterswitch == "OFF"){
  df <- dtm_EMO %>% 
    clusterer(input$clusters)

  plot <- df %>% 
    left_join(EMO_ALL, by = "Work_Order") %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = date, y = as.factor(cluster), col = MILL, shape = as.factor(PART), text = Equipment_Description_Line_1, text2 = Work_Order))+
    geom_point()+
    guides(col = "none")+
    ggtitle(label = input$filter1)
  ggplotly(plot, tooltip = c("x", "y", "col", "text", "text2", "size"))

}

})
```

However, if I add line that seeks to filter on one of those inputs, like this:

```
output$emoPlot <- renderPlotly({


if(input$prefilterswitch == "OFF"){
  df <- dtm_EMO %>% 
    filter(str_detect(combined, input$prefilterswitch %>% tolower()) ==T) %>%
    clusterer(input$clusters)

  plot <- df %>% 
    left_join(EMO_ALL, by = "Work_Order") %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = date, y = as.factor(cluster), col = MILL, shape = as.factor(PART), text = Equipment_Description_Line_1, text2 = Work_Order))+
    geom_point()+
    guides(col = "none")+
    ggtitle(label = input$filter1)
  ggplotly(plot, tooltip = c("x", "y", "col", "text", "text2", "size"))

}

})
```

Then I get my error, and no plot:

> Warning: Error in filter_impl: Evaluation error: $ operator is invalid
>   for atomic vectors.

I've had a play with rending a table output, using `renderTable` aswell, and get the same problem.  I can use inputs, but not with functions like `filter()`, and `mutate()` also has the same problem.

I suspected that perhaps the issue was to do with the inputs, but all of the switches and text fields render find in the app, and they seem to work, just not with those functions.

That's about as much as I've been able to narrow it down.  It's a little frustrating since the ability to apply multiple filters is quite important to the purpose of the app.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Not all inputs and variables are "set" the first time these reactive expressions will attempt to run. It's good practice to start a block with something like `req(input$cluster)` (see `?req`), and nothing beyond that in the chunk will execute until `input$cluster` has a valid value. You can include multiple input variables in that `req`; you can even involve arbitrary expressions that evaluate to a number, boolean, or just about anything.

Comment: Maybe you need to `req(input$prefilterswitch)` to avoid it being `NULL` when the input is initialized? But it's hard to tell without a minimal working example. -  I saw @r2evans comment too late..

Comment: `req()` works for preventing an error, but still having trouble with getting the filter evaluated. Will keep playing with it.

Comment: did you try ``base::subset`` instead of ``filter``? If this is indeed a problem with the ``filter`` function, I see no reason to not use ``subset`` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that the problem is the use of non standard evaluation in filter. In

```
 filter(str_detect(combined, input$prefilterswitch %>% tolower()))
```

you have input$prefilterswitch ... which normally in filter would be invalid because it is not just giving a column name from combined (even though we actually know that it is.  I think there is probably a check in filter that automatically throws an error if there is a `$`.    My usual solution to this is to create the object prior to starting your piping, so something like

```
 prefilterswitch <- input$prefilterswitch
```

And then reference that in the filter statement.  Also with a Boolean you don't need `==T`. 
Alternatively you can go into rlang.

Comment: Thanks for this, still haven’t got it to work. Can stop it breaking, but not actually get the filtering done. Will work on a minimal working  example with some public data.

Comment: Also try adding the dplyr:: name space.

Comment: A new day, some fresh eyes, and it turns out your answer works!  I had a couple other trivial errors adding to the confusion.  Thanks very much!

Comment: Sorry!  A bit new to this! Thanks again